# systemd killed my screen session by sigterm

Tags: debian, gnu-screen, sigterm

/var/log/syslog has following lines:

```
Mar 13 05:02:34 corben systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 1000...
Mar 13 05:02:34 corben systemd[1]: Stopped target Graphical Interface.
Mar 13 05:02:34 corben systemd[1]: session-1257696.scope: Killing process 3262 (screen) with signal SIGTERM.
Mar 13 05:02:34 corben systemd[1]: session-1257696.scope: Killing process 3263 (bash) with signal SIGTERM.
Mar 13 05:02:34 corben systemd[1]: session-1257696.scope: Killing process 3390 (bash) with signal SIGTERM.
Mar 13 05:02:34 corben systemd[1]: session-1257696.scope: Killing process 4651 (script) with signal SIGTERM.
Mar 13 05:02:34 corben systemd[1]: session-1257696.scope: Killing process 4652 (bash) with signal SIGTERM.
Mar 13 05:02:34 corben systemd[2558]: Stopped target Default.
Mar 13 05:02:34 corben systemd[2558]: Stopped target Basic System.
Mar 13 05:02:34 corben systemd[2558]: Stopped target Timers.
Mar 13 05:02:34 corben systemd[2558]: Stopped target Paths.
Mar 13 05:02:34 corben systemd[2558]: Stopped target Sockets.
Mar 13 05:02:34 corben systemd[2558]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Mar 13 05:02:34 corben systemd[2558]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
Mar 13 05:02:34 corben systemd[2558]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent (access for web browsers).
Mar 13 05:02:34 corben systemd[2558]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Mar 13 05:02:34 corben systemd[2558]: Reached target Shutdown.
Mar 13 05:02:34 corben systemd[2558]: Starting Exit the Session...
Mar 13 05:02:34 corben systemd[1]: session-1257696.scope: Killing process 4694 (bash) with signal SIGTERM.
```

my screen session with a python script working was killed by sigterm. I wonder how that happened? please help.